# MIPS single cycle datapath: How many useful subtractions and additions are performed?

Tags: mips

I have the following MIPS code that is executed only once and I need to count the number of *useful* additions and subtractions performed in total.

```
L: sub $s0,$s1,$s2
slt $s3,$s0,$s4
lw $t0,0($sp)
add $t1,$t0,$s1
beq $t1,$t3,L
```

I think that there are 11 operations in total:

```
the subtraction
PC+4
the subtraction for slt
PC+4
R[rs]+SignExtImm for lw
PC+4
the addition
PC+4 
the subtraction in ALU for beq
PC+4
PC+4+BranchAddr
```

However, 11 is not a possible choice in the multiple choice.

Comment: What are the choices? I think you are off by at least one in the count

Comment: There are 4 choices, 10 - 9 - 7 - 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did my own counts. They agree except for the `beq`

You're double counting the `PC+4` for it. AFAICT, the instruction does *either* `PC+4` or `PC+(offset << 2)` but *not* both.

So, that brings the count down from 11 to 10. This is for sure.

But, I'm not sure the `beq` uses a subtract to compare. IMO, more likely, an XOR operation [less circuitry, faster, and pretty standard logic for equality/inequality tests], so that brings the count down to 9.

YMMV ...

Comment: FYI, I did my counting [to get 9] _before_ you posted the multiple choice answers.

Comment: Thanks for your help.However, I'm still not convinced that beq does one operation out of the two. Beq does use a subtract to compare. I am certain of it.

Comment: See http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html This implies one, but, I can't recall if it's relative to PC or PC+4. If you look at the disassembly, it will be able to tell you, so that's definitive. It might be two PC adds, _if_ you were using branch delay slots. But, you'll have to make the final choice. Anyway, I'm curious myself, so when you get back the correct answer, please send me a comment

Comment: Okay, I just did the disassembly and it has -5 for the immediate, which means that it _is_ PC+4+offset, so the answer is 10 [i.e. the compare is done as an XOR]

Comment: If you are still interested, I think I found my error. I was taking for granted that slt is doing a subtraction. However, in the book(Patterson,Hennessy) it is mentioned that slt does a set-on-less-than operation, which is compare and set and not subtraction. Thanks again.

Comment: Does it say that slt is a compare? See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_comparator slt is an ALU type inst, so it _could_ be done as sub with extra logic before T5 [to minimize gates of separate comparator]. If slt _is_ a comparator, then [as noted in link] equality is an AND, so beq/bne is even simpler than numeric compare. So, if slt is not sub, then bne is less likely to be an ALU op. To prevent ALU from being a bottleneck, branch inst unit might do its own PC+4 [still counts as add, but does not use ALU] add circuit and do AND for the compare. So, 9??? What does prof say?